# How to remove the gap between navigation icon and toolbar logo?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How can I remove the margin between the navigation icon and toolbar logo.

My toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/paper9patch"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am inserting logo like this

```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   toolbar.setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(0);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.sample);
```

my toolbar is looking like this

[image]

the logo is almost showing in the middle I want it beside the drawer icon

I searched on stackover flow and all answers tell to use

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

but its not working . I can say there is no padding for the image it is cropped exactly to edges. If i use tile there is no gap in middle ,the gap appears only when inserted logo.

[image]

Is this intended behavior ? Is there any thing else I can do to remove the gap?

Edit : styles i am using

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

   <style name="toolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme">

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/themeColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/themeColor</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: because your logo is not trimmed, Your logo having spaces around image content. please trim your logo and try to use it

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya i already mentioned in the question that  `I can say there is no padding for the image it is cropped exactly to edges`

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/paper9patch"` what is this?

Comment: It is a 9 patch image i used to get shadow below toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was with the image , It did not had any extra space or padding at side but the image resolution was higher .

**Solution is** :

Just decrease the image resolution of logo and every thing should work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/paper9patch"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: thank you , I already know this , i just want to know why above thing is not working , Am i doing it wrong or is it intended behavior

Comment: @Redman `Am i doing it wrong` i think not because `app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` is working fine in my device

Comment: is logo appearing beside the drawer icon in your device ?

Comment: @Redman yes i didn't apply any this theme `app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/toolbarTheme"`

Comment: i don't have any thing in those themes

`<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`

Comment: ` <style name="toolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/themeColor</item>
        
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/themeColor</item>

    </style>`

Comment: ya i think so too , i dont know why it is give such issue , so the best thing i can do is to do as you suggested ?

Comment: no, the problem was with image, when i use launcher icon it worked fine , but when i used my image the problem was occuring .Problem is that the image is perfectly fine, there are no extra spaces at end it is cropped exactly to the edges. trying to figure out whats causing problem with that image

Comment: yes , just had to decrease the resolution of my image

Answer (score 1):

Try this although it not much different from your layout but its works well i have tested it .

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Set up toobar as.

```
Toolbar  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New");
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Tried no use still same

Comment: I have attached the output of my test . didn't you get the same result ? If not post your style for that activity .

Comment: no i got my old result, no change at all .I think it gives problem with drawer icon ,don't know why

Comment: Well I have tried. I think your image can be a problem . Use ic_launcher android icon for test as logo . If not resolve edit your question with style of activity.

Comment: Your theme looks Ok . Seems like the problem with the logo you were using . Thx .